# Using Php to execute command line

Tags: php, command-line, cmd

I got some problem while using php to execute command line.

I have a software and I need to execute the software to export pdf by using cmd 
command line.

(The software need to be executed by using command-line)

Therefore i wrote a php code.

```
<?php 
$cmd ='C:\XmlServer.exe C:\input.xml';   
shell_exec($cmd);
?>
```

I've tried the string 'C:\XmlServer.exe C:\input.xml' is working on cmd.

But I can't using php to execute command line to get the same result.

I also tried `exec($cmd);`, but it still didn't work.

Could anyone help me solving the problem?

I want to run php just like running command line.

I wrote like the following in command line:

```
C:\> XmlServer.exe input.xml
```

then it's ok to output a file for me.
but using the same code in php didn't work.

--
Update

using `echo shell_exec($cmd);` is okay, but no output.

Comment: Have you checked your error logs?

Comment: also do `echo shell_exec()` to see the output of your command.

Comment: There is noting just blank(no error) in log. I think there is something wrong. when i echo exec($cmd)  or shell_exec($cmd), runing php on webpage and it shows the version of xmlserver and when it is released.... So I need to try one more time...

Comment: it seem the php  is ok but no pdf is produced.

Answer (score 0):

try with echo like that :

```
<?php  
  $cmd ='C:\XmlServer.exe input.xml';    
  echo exec($cmd);
?>
```